# Php OOP Class Extensions

Tags: php, oop

I have 3 main classes that i use throughout my application. They are also used in every other class that i create. I am new to PDO i am trying to avoid using these classes by passing them as parameters and defining them within the construct of each class. I have looked into class extensions but i am not sure if it the right way to go. My application is completed. The goal is to make the changes without requiring a rewrite of all of my classes. Here is a brief example below

```
class Example {
    public function __construct($db, $utility, $sanitize){
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->utility = $utility;
        $this->sanitize = $sanitize;
    }

    function example2() {
        return $this->utility->getIP();
    }
}
```

this is just an example of how i currently have things set up. I would like to keep the same format of defining the variables within the construct so they stay the same and do not require me to rewrite all of the classes.

Comment: Did you look at `interface` and `abstract` ?

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you mean, do you intend to create an instance of these three within the __construct() function of every class that uses these, as a means of encapsulation? If so, you can do that, but providing the dependencies as parameters (you should annotate their type though) allows easier test mocking. This principle is called dependency injection.

Comment: Have you looked at `traits`?